# Unable to access content in JSON parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in RoR and I follow some tutorials like Rails for Zombie and I have a problem in an integration test function :

```
test 'returns user by id' do
    get "/users", {id: @user.id}, { :authorization => token_header(@user.authentication_token)}
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
    Rails.logger.debug "TEST: #{user_response}"
    assert_equal @user.email, user_response[:email]
end
```

And I get this error :

```
ListingUsersTest#test_returns_user_by_id:
   TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
   test/integration/listing_users_test.rb:23:in `[]'
   test/integration/listing_users_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:ListingUsersTest>'
```

I thought user_response was empty or nil or something like that but in my log :

```
TEST: [{:id=>428186149, :email=>"name.surname@host.com",...}]
```

So I am just wondering if I hadn't miss something with hash structure or.. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *an array* in your JSON:

```
user_response[0][:email]
# => "name.surname@host.com"
```

The error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

suggests that the `[]` expected an `Integer`, but got a `Symbol`. This is a hint that although you are expecting a hash there, chances are that you have an array.